# SQL: How to insert multiple values in a cell from existing rows?

Tags: sql, flyway

My problem is as follows.

I have a database with certain Healthcare services. These services can have 1 or more emails that are stored in HealthcareServiceEmail with a foreign key referencing HealthcareService. I would like to show these emails in the Healthcareservice TABLE.

For this I would need to insert the values from HealthcareserviceEmail INTO the table Healthcareservice where their foreign key matches the key from Healthcareservice.

Because there can be multiple emails I would need to insert multiple values in the same cell. I would also need to insert them into already existing rows from healthcareservice (If I understand correctly). What I have for now is this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ADMINISTRATION.HealthcareServiceEmail (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255),
    healthcareService_id BIGINT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    uuid VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE ADMINISTRATION.HealthcareServiceEmail
ADD FOREIGN KEY (healthcareService_id)
REFERENCES ADMINISTRATION.HealthcareService (id) DEFERRABLE;


INSERT INTO ADMINISTRATION.HealthcareService (email)
SELECT email from ADMINISTRATION.HealthcareServiceEmail
WHERE ADMINISTRATION.HealthcareserviceEmail (healthcareService_id) = ADMINISTRATION.HealthcareService (id)
```

Now this obviously does not work, but I am not fully sure what to do to solve this as I have looked into SQL but it is definitely not my strong suit.

Answer (score 0):

> I would need to insert multiple values in the same cell

This is fundamentally not going to work. One cell, one (possibly NULL) value. The reason to have a second table, in this case `ADMINISTRATION.HealthcareServiceEmail`, is to be able to represent a one-to-many relationship between the things the database is representing, in this case associating multiple emails with a single Service.

There are other ways to do this; for example, have a column `Emails` in the Service table, which contains *all* the emails for that service, concatenated into a single string - but this is a lot harder to work with when it comes to deleting or updating a single email for a service. Whether this is in any way desirable depends on...

> I would like to show these emails in the Healthcareservice TABLE

... *why* you want to do this. If, say, this is so that you can create a UI where each service has all its emails listed, that is work best done in the UI logic. Let the database express the relationships between entities in the most natural way, and  let your UI figure out how to arrange them into an aesthetic form.